# Connection with SQL Server 2014 with node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am unable to connect to my SQL Server 2014 from node server.

I get this error:

> Failed to connect to 192.168.1.3,2207:2207:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 192.168.1.3,2207:2207'

TCP port also enabled but same issue

Comment: `192.168.1.3` is an IP address. What's the `,2207:2207` doing there? If it's intended to be a port number, it's clearly not being respected, given the `:1433` at the end (which is the default port for SQL Server). You should probably give more details on your setup and the code you're using to connect.

Answer (score 0):

By using knex i resolve this problem

connection: {
    server : 'IP Address',
     user : 'sa',
     password : '******',
     database : '*****',
    options: {
      port: 14831
    }
   }